# gnome-terminal and multiple ssh to different computers

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

I am working with gnome-terminal and trying to set up a bash script to do the following:

1. Open up a new gnome-terminal - got that working
2. in the new window, ssh to another computer (let's call it XYZ) - got that working

This is what is NOT working:

3. In that (XYZ) computer, I want to ssh to another computer (call it ABC)

Point 1 is the only way we can get to computer ABC, so don't ask. :)

I can open the window, ssh to XYZ, but how do I have another ssh command to fire off? I cannot use a .script on computer XYZ to fire off an SSH because we have multiple shells open (up to 10-12) where they ssh to XYZ, then ssh to several computers.

Comment: You are searching for `ssh -o ProxyCommand=...` to *directly* connect to ABC with XYZ as your proxy

Comment: Awesome!  Tank you...now to figure out how to send a /usr/bin/cd command...Got any ideas for that? :) 

I tried putting that command in with the ssh command (per the documents) but now the gnome-terminal immediately closes down...